# Sessão não faz logoff em php

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Estou criando um pequeno site, porem quando aperto para sair, o site desloga, mas se eu coloco o link de uma das páginas, consigo entrar no sistema e não verifica se foi efetuado o login, mesmo com campos de segurança

Login.php:

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 texto-capa">
    <form method="POST" action="validalogin.php">
      <img class="mb-4" src="imagens/icon/android-icon-72x72.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h3>Área de Login</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>E-mail</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail..." />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Senha</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha..."/>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
         <label>
           <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Relembre-me
         </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar"><b>ENTRAR</b></button><br>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018</p>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center text-danger">
      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['security'])){
          echo $_SESSION['security'];
          unset($_SESSION['security']);
        } 
      ?>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Security.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
if($_SESSION['login'] == null || $_SESSION['id'] == null){
  $_SESSION['security'] = "Efetue o Login!";
  header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Fechar.php

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['login'], $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['usuario']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Testa mudando o `== null` por `== ""` (string vazia)

Comment: Já tentei, mas não funcionou :/

Comment: Testa então `isset($_SESSION ["nome"])`, se não der faz um `echo` da variável de sessão e coloca na pergunta

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou nem o echo

Comment: Verifica se a sessão foi iniciada em todas as páginas  (`session_start ()`), tente trocar `ob_start` por `session_start`, se nao me engano para usar o ob também precisa usar `ob_end_flush()`

Comment: Em todas, consegue postar um exemplo que funcione e não burle a segurança do site ?

Comment: Até onde sei pra poder manipular a variável de sessão é necessário chamar a função `session_start();` antes de qualquer outro código php (`<?php session_start(); ...`,  sobre a segurança disso ja não sei dizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para não editar a pergunta e ficar sem nexo consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

Em todas minhas páginas php, que o usuário ficará com a sessão ativa, contem um uma verificação inicia:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) == null)
{
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("Efetue seu Login!");';
  echo 'window.location.href="login.php"';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

Porem, em minha página fechar.php alterei inteiramente o código, para apagar todos os dados da $_SESSION:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Apaga todas as variáveis da sessão
$_SESSION = array();

// Se é preciso matar a sessão, então os cookies de sessão também devem ser 
apagados.
// Nota: Isto destruirá a sessão, e não apenas os dados!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
header("Location: login.php");
}

// Por último, destrói a sessão
session_destroy();
?>
```

Desta maneira, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você não deve ter colocado todo o código aqui, eu assumo que o falta é o exit após o header no security.php:

```
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
```

Independente de isso resolver o seu problema ou não, é uma boa prática de programação em PHP você colocar o `exit` após a utilização do `header('Location:...')`.

Também certifique-se que você esteja usando `session_start()` em algum lugar do seu código antes de usar o `unset()`.

Comment: Todos os php´s iniciam com session_start(), mas não funciona nenhuma alteração, incluir exit em todas páginas que jogam um header no final..

Comment: Então tenta trocar o $_SESSION[xx]==null por isset($_SESSION[..])..

Comment: Consegui resolver, conforme resposta abaixo, obrigado!